# How to enumerate only those properties/methods of JavaScript objects added at runtime?

Tags: javascript

The scenario: I'm trying to figure out an existing HTML/JavaScript site with a convoluted API.  It adds several properties to the `window` object.  I'd like to enumerate only those properties that are not builtins or defaults (e.g. exclude `window.location`, `window.parent`, etc.)

Is there an idiomatic JavaScript way to do this?  I'd thought of doing a shallow copy in a blank HTML page, then "subtracting" those properties somehow when enumerating the real one.

Ideally, i'd want a way to dump objects to the console or in a watch as if none of the regular `window` properties existed, only those added with JavaScript source.

Comment: Can you execute some script before this "convoluted API" ? If so you can make an array of the window's properties and exclude them when enumerating later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on [dystroy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12588406/128165), in the case where you cannot execute your code before the api, you can create a new window on the fly to grab its properties (*since it will be 'clean'*)
(*also using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to exclude inherited properties*)

```
window.preexistingkeys = [];

var w = window.open();
for (var key in w) if(window.hasOwnProperty(key)) window.preexistingkeys.push(key);
w.close();


for (var key in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(key) && window.preexistingkeys.indexOf(key)==-1) console.log(key, window[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a detailled version of what I proposed in comment :

```
window.preexistingkeys = [];
for (var key in window) window.preexistingkeys.push(key);

// your convoluted api here

for (var key in window) {
    if (window.preexistingkeys.indexOf(key)==-1) console.log(key, window[key]);
}
​
```

[with a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmYAf/)

Note that you may execute the first part at start of the page's header, before the import of external scripts. [Here's a sample](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/window.html).